# Query to derive schedules from multiple punches

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having trouble building a query that has just one schedule each day for each employee. The data I'm manipulating records each punch in time and each punch out time. The query I was using was working fine until I ran into schedules that spanned overnight. Below is the query I was using and some sample data.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID
,min(PUNCHIN) AS PUNCHIN
,max(PUNCHOUT) AS PUNCHOUT
FROM EMPSCHED
WHERE PUNCHIN <> PUNCHOUT 
GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID
,CAST(PUNCHIN AS DATE)
order by EMPID, PUNCHIN
```

Sample Table:

```
EMPLOYEEID  PUNCHIN             PUNCHOUT
DGHAG   2020-07-10 20:00:00.000 2020-07-11 01:45:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-11 01:45:00.000 2020-07-11 02:15:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-11 02:15:00.000 2020-07-11 06:30:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-11 06:30:00.000 2020-07-11 06:30:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-11 20:00:00.000 2020-07-11 23:30:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-11 23:30:00.000 2020-07-12 00:00:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-12 00:00:00.000 2020-07-12 06:30:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-12 06:30:00.000 2020-07-12 06:30:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-12 20:00:00.000 2020-07-13 02:15:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-13 02:15:00.000 2020-07-13 02:45:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-13 02:45:00.000 2020-07-13 06:30:00.000
DGHAG   2020-07-13 06:30:00.000 2020-07-13 06:30:00.000
DGHFA   2020-07-08 08:30:00.000 2020-07-08 13:30:00.000
DGHFA   2020-07-08 13:30:00.000 2020-07-08 13:30:00.000
DGHFA   2020-07-09 08:30:00.000 2020-07-09 13:30:00.000
DGHFA   2020-07-09 13:30:00.000 2020-07-09 13:30:00.000
DGHFA   2020-07-11 08:30:00.000 2020-07-11 13:30:00.000
DGHFA   2020-07-11 13:30:00.000 2020-07-11 13:30:00.000
```

The goal is to have one record for each shift, flattening the schedules down to the first punch of the day to the last punch of the shift, whether it's the same day or the following one.

Create Table Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMPSCHED](
    [EMPLOYEEID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PUNCHIN] [datetime] NULL,
    [PUNCHOUT] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will detect all gaps in the schedule (breaks or end of shift) regardless of the length of the shift (it can span multiple days).

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    EMPLOYEEID
    ,LAG(PUNCHOUT) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEEID ORDER BY PUNCHIN ASC) as last_punchout
    ,PUNCHIN
    ,PUNCHOUT
    ,LEAD(PUNCHIN) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEEID ORDER BY PUNCHIN ASC) as next_punchin
  FROM EMPSCHED
  WHERE PUNCHIN <> PUNCHOUT 
)
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEEID
  ,PUNCHIN
  ,PUNCHOUT
FROM CTE 
WHERE last_punchout <> PUNCHIN 
OR PUNCHOUT <> next_punchin 
OR last_punchout is null 
OR next_punchin is null
```

You can play around with it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b651d6614d14ccec2f8da4d63f5f6a2f

Comment: Thanks, gives me something to work with. However, for the first employee (DGHAG) I'd be looking for something like
DGHAG   7-10-2020 20:00 7-11-2020 06:30

You'll see there's not actually a gap in the punches, they punch out at 1:45 and punch back in at 1:45. I'd like to basically ignore that and go with the first punch and last punch.